# Null context in a Spring flow

Tags: spring

I am trying to customize the login process in Shibboleth IdP 3.0. It's basically a Spring web application, that amongst other things uses Spring flows.

I am getting the following exception (null context):

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E:(pos 23): Method call: Attempted to call method verify(java.lang.String) on null context object
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.throwIfNotNullSafe(MethodReference.java:144)
```

It happens on the evaluate expression below, in this Spring web flow:

```
<action-state id="VerifyOtp">
    <set name="flowScope.enteredOtp" value="requestParameters.j_otp"
         type="java.lang.String" />
    <set name="flowScope.otpSecretKey" 
        value="keyManager.findSecretKey(flowScope.otpUsername)" 
         type="ch.eifr.oshi.jaas.totp.SecretKey" />

    <evaluate expression="flowScope.otpSecretKey.verify(flowScope.enteredOtp)" 
                  result="flowScope.otpIsValid" />

    <transition on="#{  flowScope.otpIsValid }" to="proceed" />
    <transition on="#{ !flowScope.otpIsValid }" to="DisplayOtpPage" />
</action-state>
```

The flow imports the following beans:

(`keyManager` gets instantiated as expected)

```
<bean class="ch.eifr.oshi.jaas.totp.SecretKeysManagerImpl" id="keyManager" scope="singleton" />
<bean class="ch.eifr.oshi.jaas.totp.SecretKey" scope="prototype" />
```

I tried with and without the last line, it made no difference. I thought maybe I had to tell Spring about the classes it needs to load. That doesn't seem to be the case.

I think my problem is related to scope or dependencies, because I tried calling `keyManager.toString()` in a view and it returned something.

But if I call `keyManager.findSecretKey('john.doe').getId()` I get a null context exception. Note that the `findSecretKey(String)` method always returns a new key, it never returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to do it a better way, but only this worked:

```
<action-state id="ExtractOtpFromFormRequestAndValidate">
    <set name="flashScope.enteredOtp" value="requestParameters.j_otp" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <transition on="#{ keyManager.findSecretKey(flowScope.otpUsername).verify(flashScope.enteredOtp) }" to="proceed" />
    <transition to="DisplayOtpPage" />
</action-state>
```